# Java printing to a printer dependant on choice

Tags: java, printing, jcombobox, aspose

I am developing a Java application which pulls an attachment from a notes database, carries out a find and replace on the document, and sends it to a printer depending on what printer is specified in the program settings.

The settings work through the use of a JComboBox and the PrintService class, I am getting the list of installed printers on the machine using PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices and populating the combobox with its results. To carry out the find and replace, and send to the printer I am using Aspose.Words. To send the document to the printer using Aspose it is simply Document.print("Printer name"). This is as simple as passing the comboboxes "getSelectedItem.toString();" into the Document.print function but my problem is networked printers which the program is heavily dependant on.

In word a networked printer would be specified as "HQ Printer on UKTESTSERV01" if it was on the server UKTESTSERVER01 but the value returned in PrintServiceLookup is "\UKTESTSERV01\HQ Printer". This is not recognised as a Microsoft word printer when passed into the print function and therefore it prints to the default.

I am looking for another solution, possibly using another printing class or maybe a class that will list Microsoft words printers. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Ross.

Code is below, I have left a lot of it out and only included the relevant area.

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
        null, null);
String[] printers = {"No Printer", "No Printer", "No Printer", 
        "No Printer", "No Printer", "No Printer", "No Printer",
        "No Printer","No Printer"};
int i = 0;

for (PrintService printer : printServices){
    printers[i] = printer.getName();
    i++;
}

final JComboBox printerCombo1 = new JComboBox(printers);
printerCombo1.setBounds(109, 11, 295, 20);
getContentPane().add(printerCombo1);

String specifiedPrinter = printerCombo1.getSelectedItem().toString();

document.print(specifiedPrinter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Document.print(AttributeSet)` instead of `Document.print(String)` method to specify the printer *(check [API Reference](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/com.aspose.words.Document+class#com.aspose.words.Documentclass-MethodSummary))*. Here is the code example.

```
String printerName = combobox.getSelectedItem().toString();
for (PrintService p: PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null)) {
    if (p.getName().equals(printerName)) {
        doc.print(p.getAttributes());
        break;
    }
}
```

PS. I am a developer at Aspose.